# how to output data from one page to another from the collection of the selected item?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have two XAML pages and one their common ViewModel page.I want to output data from one page to another from the collection of the selected item. It must be Label`s Text.
I have 2 problems

1)I can not bind text from label to the object field

2)If I bind Label`s Text to a variable.I can see data only on the current page. But if I go to another page and place the same label there, the information is not displayed.I do not understand why so because on the next page the same variable which already contains data

FIRST XAML PAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.TryPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView  x:Name="AddCar" ItemsSource="{Binding Hearts}"      
                  SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                Span="2" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="135" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Frame CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" Padding="0" >
                                <Button 
                           CornerRadius="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="135" WidthRequest="150"
                         BackgroundColor="{Binding CustButtonColor}" ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
                          Command="{ Binding BindingContext.ChangeColor, 
                           Source={x:Reference Name=AddCar} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <Label x:Name="small12" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Start"  Text="{Binding  tryHeart.TypeHeart}" />
        <Button Text="Navigate" Command="{Binding navigateCommand }">
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
 public partial class TryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TryPageCS(this.Navigation);
        }
    }
```

VIEW MODEL PAGE

```
 public   class TryPageCS : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public ObservableCollection<CircleColor> Hearts { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChangeColor { protected set; get; }

    public TryHeart tryHeart { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public Command navigateCommand { get; set; }

    public async Task GotoPage2()
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
    }



    public TryPageCS(INavigation navigation)
    {
        tryHeart = new TryHeart();

        this.Navigation = navigation;
        this.navigateCommand = new Command(async () => await GotoPage2());


        Hearts = new ObservableCollection<CircleColor>();
        Hearts.Add(new CircleColor() { Name = "one", Image = "heart", CustButtonColor = Color.White });
        Hearts.Add(new CircleColor() { Name = "two", Image =  "heart", CustButtonColor = Color.White });
        Hearts.Add(new CircleColor() { Name = "three", Image = "heart", CustButtonColor = Color.White });
        Hearts.Add(new CircleColor() { Name = "four", Image = "heart", CustButtonColor = Color.White });
  
        var DefaultCars = new ObservableCollection<CircleColor>();
        DefaultCars = Hearts;

        ChangeColor = new Command<CircleColor>((key) =>
        {

            foreach (var item in Hearts)
            {
                item.CustButtonColor = Color.White;
                item.Image = "heart";
            }
            var car = key as CircleColor;
            car.CustButtonColor = Color.LightCoral;
            tryHeart.TypeHeart = car.Name;
            
        });
    }
}
```

SECOND PAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
              xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>

        <Label  FontSize="Large"   Text="{Binding  tryHeart.TypeHeart}" />
    
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TryPageCS(this.Navigation);

        }

    }
```

Also I have a class

```
 public class TryHeart : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string typeHeart;

        public string TypeHeart
        {
            set
            {
                if (typeHeart != value)
                {
                    typeHeart = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TypeHeart");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return typeHeart;
            }

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I will explain why I need it. In my real project I have to collect information about the car from different pages. object of this class it will be my machine. Therefore I want to write down the collected data in object of a class and then on the last page to display data

On the SECOND XAML PAGE I write only THE SAME LABEL

```
 <Label x:Name="small123" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  Text="{Binding   Name}" />
```

Please,help me with my 2 problems
1)Why I can not to write

```
<Label x:Name="small12" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  Text="{Binding    tryHeart.TypeHeart}" />
```

Information does not display

2)How I must display information from one page from collection view of selected item to another page

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Navigation does not contain a definition for PushModalAsync

Comment: `tryHeart` has to be a public property.  You can only bind to public properties

Comment: I made but it does not work

Comment: <Label x:Name="small12" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Start"  Text="{Binding   tryHeart.TypeHeart}" />

Comment: do you know what a C# public property is?  This is NOT --> `public TryHeart tryHeart = new TryHeart();`

Comment: Oh,sorry,I understood and edited.It solved my first problem.Can you help me with second?

Comment: you can either pass selected data or an entire VM via the constructor when you navigate to Page2.  Pages are just C# classes so you can pass data using any of the normal C# mechanisms

Comment: sorry but I did not understood good it,can you explain once more please?

Comment: `Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(data1,data2,etc));`

Comment: What is data1,data2?It for example object or property?

Comment: it is whatever you need to pass.  It could be an entire VM, or individual properties, etc

Comment: Can I add function

Comment: private async void AddMark(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
        }

Comment: in my ViewModel?Because I have error and VS does not want to fix it

Comment: "an error" is not a helpful description of the problem

Comment: one second,i will edit my question

Comment: TryPageCS is not a Page.  Navigation is a property of page types

Comment: Okey.Sorry,what I need to do?If I have VM page and I need to transfer to from VM to another page?

Comment: the page does the Navigation.  The page can pass data from it's VM to another page, as I demonstrated above

Comment: In my code behind I make as you said,but VS can not find property from VM

Comment: please show the actual code you are trying to write and the specific error message it gives you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For question 1

**TryHeart** in the ViewModel is a private property in your case . You need to set it as **public** .

```
public TryHeart tryHeart {get;set;}
```

```
public TryPageCS()
{
  //...
  tryHeart = new TryHeart();
  //...
}
```

### For question 2

If you want to handle navigation logic in VM , you need to pass the current navigation from current page .

#### in ViewModel

Add a property

```
INavigation CurrentNavigation { get; set; }

public TryPageCS(INavigation navigation)
{
    CurrentNavigation = navigation;
}
```

And now you can use the property in the method

```
await CurrentNavigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
```

#### in ContentPage

Pass the Navigation as params

```
BindingContext = new TryPageCS(this.Navigation);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can go to another Page but Label on another page did not display data/Label on another Page:

Comment: <Label  FontSize="Large"   Text="{Binding  tryHeart.TypeHeart}" />

Comment: Why don't you binding Name directly ? tryHeart in your VM is private . So it will never work .

Comment: I delete Name and made as you said in For question 1

Comment: Did you set the value of tryHeart.TypeHeart?

Comment: A edited.On current page I see data but on the another no